# CSS Height Property of an Image

Tags: css

Is there any difference  in the following image CSS properties wrt height?

```
height: auto; 

height: 100%;
```

Answer (score 2):

`height: auto` will allow the image to grow to it's original size with no distortion but may overlap the parent element.

`height: 100%` will shrink or stretch the image height to match the height of it's parent

```html
height: auto
<div style="height: 100px; border: 2px solid red;">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" style="height: auto">
</div>

<br><br><br><br>
height: 100%
<div style="height: 100px;; border: 2px solid yellow;">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" style="height: 100%">
</div>
```